# NullPointerException while Encoding a Url android

Tags: java, android, urlencode

I am trying to encode a certain url by using the following code:

```
myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    Login myLogin = new Login();
    url = myLogin.AuthUrl;
    try 
    {

        String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

But I get the following error:-

```
 02-27 15:21:57.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-27 15:21:57.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-27 15:21:57.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
    02-27 15:21:57.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
    02-27 15:21:57.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): at com.abcdef.abcd.Details.onCreate(Details.java:42)
```

What could be going wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is written in 42nd line?

Comment: Use this `String query = URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");` i think you have set `UTF-8 ` in upper case may be that is causing issue. I am not sure whether it is correct or not but just give a try.

Comment: @SagarShah Its the same line I have mentioned in the question. ie `String encoded = UrlEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");`

Comment: The code snippet you post will not throw that exception. In your actual code, you're passing a `null` string to `URLEncoder.encode()`

Comment: @InnocentKiller Capitalization doesn't matter on the charset; either will work fine (although the capitalized version is the correct form).

Comment: And if the encoding is wrong it would return an UnsupportedEncodingException as you can read in the Documentation and not an NullPointerException

Comment: pls post your onCreate

Comment: @Yogendra the url is valid

Comment: @user3354605 What does your `Login` class extend? Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is inside your `Login()` ?

```
Login myLogin = new Login();
```

pls log and check if myLogin object has the url.

String encoded = UrlEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");

should be:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
```

If you have declared it as a variable, then is it initialized properly.

Pls check if you are getting the same error with URLEncoder (when used directly, no variable)

Comment: If the encoding is wrong it would return an UnsupportedEncodingException as you can read in the Documentation and not an NullPointerException

Comment: @ReeCube the capital - "URLE.." -wouldn't it give a compile time error too?

Comment: @user2450263 : **"wouldn't it give a compile time error too?"** - Not if the OP has happened to defined a field called `UrlEncoder` but then again it still wouldn't show a stacktrace like that.

Comment: @Squonk :) , true ,agreed

Comment: @user2450263 sorry but i can't see any difference between the first case and the case to replace?

Comment: @ReeCube http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html  define it as URLEncoder. What has been used is UrlEncoder - the R and L

Comment: @user2450263 sorry didn't realize it

Comment: @User2450263 I have declared a variable as `URLEncoder UrlEncoder`

Answer (score 1):

This is the source for the encode method of [libcore.net.UriCodec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-4.1_r2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/UriCodec.java) ...

```
public final String encode(String s, Charset charset) {
    // Guess a bit larger for encoded form
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 16);
    appendEncoded(builder, s, charset, false);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Line 132 is shown in the stacktrace...

```
02-27 15:21:57.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
```

...this is the line...

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 16);
```

The only way it can throw an NPE is at `s.length`. In other words you're passing in a null string for the url.

EDIT: Looking at the extra code you've posted, it seems creating a new instance of your `Login` class doesn't initialise the `AuthUrl` field so url is null.

```
Login myLogin = new Login();
url = myLogin.AuthUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch around like this:

```
        try 
        {
            encoded = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
            txt1.setText(encoded);
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```